# Laravel Roles and Permissions Packages

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles, laravel-routing, laravel-authentication

I want to create roles and permissions like the following:

Each `post` has many `users`.

1. Type A user can do everything (create, edit, update and delete) the
   post.
2. Type B user can only create, edit and update the post.
3. Type C user can only edit and update the post.

Will this work with the `santigarcor/laratrust` or `spatie/laravel-permission` packages? Those packages look very complicated.

Comment: try laravel entrust

Comment: I usually use laravel-permission by spatie. BUT seems it wont help you in this situation. If you are worry about these packages you can just use Policies (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#creating-policies). They are well suited for your needs and do not require installation of packages.

Comment: you can see here autorization gates with roles and permissions https://laravel-news.com/authorization-gates

Comment: *Will this work with Laratrust or spatie/laravel-permission? Packages look very complicated.* What does that mean? Its complicated topic and spatie's package does great job abstracting it.

Comment: @Kyslik As they are complicated so I wanted to know if there are other ways to implement.

Comment: Everything you are trying to do is pretty easy with Policies, no need for a package. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization

Comment: @Christophvh Thanks for comment. Cool to hear that~!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a basic authorization feature, laravel's default [gates and policies](https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust) (as mentioned in the comments) would do the trick.

If are looking for features similar to that of [page roles in Facebook pages](https://www.facebook.com/help/289207354498410), where you have different groups each with its own posts, and users who have different permissions in different groups, then take a look at the teams feature in the [laratrust](https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust) package.